# jqGrid :: Can't clear search value in reordered column which uses stype:select

Tags: jqgrid

I can't find any hint in the web concerning the following problem:
After reordering a column which uses a drop down box (containing relevant search terms) I can't clear a selected value (with x) from the toolbar anymore.

Could it be that this is a undetected bug in jqGrid?

I appreciate any help!
Thanks a lot.

I use jqGrid  4.7.0:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">     
//<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function (){
        // Hilfsvariablen   
        var selRowData = null;
        var bLinkedTables = false;
        var sLoginStatus = "public";
        var bColumnChooser_CustomersOverview = false;
        var iColumnIndex;
        var iColumnNewWidth;

        // Hauptfunktion :: Definition der Tabelle BVB-Kundenuebersicht 
        jQuery("#list_CustomersOverview").jqGrid({
            url:'./jqGridResults/xmlCustomersOverview.jsp',
            datatype:"xml",
            mtype: "POST",          
            colNames:[
                'KB-Id',
                'Kunde (Vollbez.)',
                'Kundenbibl. (Vollbez.)',
                'Kunde (Kurzbez.)',
                'Kundenbibl. (Kurzbez.)',
                'Straße',
                'PLZ',
                'Ort',
                'Typ',
                'ISIL',
                'Sigel',
                'LOW',
                'Leit-ISIL'
            ],
            colModel:[
                {
                    name: 'libraries_id',
                    index:'libraries.id',
                    id:'libraries.id',
                    width:70,
                    hidedlg: true,
                    hidden:true,
                    editable:false,
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','le','lt','gt','ge']}
                },
                {
                    name: 'customers.name_full',
                    index:'customers.name_full',
                    width:255,
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{
                        placeholder:"Vollbezeichnung",
                        defaultValue:function(){
                            var sSelRowData = JSON.stringify(selRowData);
                            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(sSelRowData);
                            return selRowData === null ? '' :obj["customers.name_full"]; 
                        }
                    },
                    editrules:{
                        edithidden:true,
                        required:true,
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en'], searchhidden:true},
                    formoptions:{label:'Kunde (Vollbez.) <span style="color:red;">*</span>'}
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.name_full',
                    index:'libraries.name_full', 
                    width:150,
                    editable:true,
                    editrules:{
                        edithidden:true,
                        custom: true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"Vollbezeichnung"},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en'],searchhidden: true},
                },
                {
                    name: 'customers.name_short',
                    index:'customers.name_short',
                    width:255,
                    editable:true,
                    editrules:{
                        edithidden:true,
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"Kurzbezeichnung"},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en'],searchhidden: true},
                    hidden:true
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.name_short',
                    index:'libraries.name_short',
                    width:150,
                    editable:true,
                    editrules:{
                        edithidden:true,
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"Kurzbezeichnung"},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en'],searchhidden: true},
                    hidden:true
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.location_street',
                    index:'libraries.location_street',
                    width:120,
                    editable:true,
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"Hauptsitz"},
                    formoptions:{label:"Straße und Hausnr."},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']}
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.location_zip',
                    index:'libraries.location_zip', 
                    width:82,
                    editable:true,
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"z.B. 12345"},
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','eq','ne']},
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.location_city',
                    index:'libraries.location_city',
                    width:105, 
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"Stadt"},
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']}
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.type_of_institution',
                    index:'libraries.type_of_institution',
                    width:115,
                    editable:true,
                    edittype:"select",
                    editoptions:{value:"B:Behördenbibliothek;F:Fachhochschulbibliothek;H:Hochschulbibliohek;K:Kirchliche Bibliothek;Ö:Öffentliche Bibliothek;R:Regional Staatliche Bibliothek;S:Spezialbibliothek;U:Universitätsbibliothek;Z:Zweigbibliothek"},
                    stype:'select',
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne'], value:":Alle;B:Behördenbibliothek;F:Fachhochschulbibliothek;H:Hochschulbibliohek;K:Kirchliche Bibliothek;Ö:Öffentliche Bibliothek;R:Regional Staatliche Bibliothek;S:Spezialbibliothek;U:Universitätsbibliothek;Z:Zweigbibliothek"}
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.icode_isil',
                    index:'libraries.icode_isil', 
                    width:85,
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"z.B. DE-M37"},
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']},
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.icode_sigel',
                    index:'libraries.icode_sigel',
                    width:85,
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"z.B. M 37"},
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']},
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.icode_low',
                    index:'libraries.icode_low',
                    width:85,
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"z.B. DAV01"},
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']},
                },
                {
                    name: 'libraries.icode_isil_of_leader_lib',
                    index:'libraries.icode_isil_of_leader_lib',
                    width:85,
                    editable:true,
                    editoptions:{placeholder:"z.B. DE-19"},
                    editrules:{
                        custom:true,
                        custom_func:validateInput
                    },
                    searchoptions:{sopt:['bw','bn','cn','nc','eq','ne','ew','en']},
                },
            ],
            // Tabellenbreite proportional anpassen
            shrinkToFit: false,
            // Spalten via Maustaste umordnen
            sortable: true,
            // ID der Navigationsleiste
            pager: "#pager_CustomersOverview",
            // Ueberschrift
            caption: "BVB-Kunden&uuml;bersicht",
            // Initiale Inhaltssortierung
            sortname: "customers.name_full",
            // Initiale Sortierrichtung
            sortorder: "asc",
            // Zebrastreifen
            altRows: true,
            // Zeilen highlighten (z.B. bei onmouseover) 
            hoverrows: true,
            // Tabellenhoehe    
            height: "230",
            // Anzahl der angezeigten Tupel auf einer Tabellenseite
            rowNum: 1000,
            // Initialer Tabellenzustand
            hiddengrid: false,
            // Anzeige der Tupelnummer 
            rownumbers: true,
            // Optionale Tupelanzahl pro Tabellenseite
            rowList: [1000,500,100,50,20,10],
            // Anzeige "Zeige X bis Y aus Z" in der PagerBar
            viewrecords: true,
            // Alle Daten werden auf einmal geladen (Speedvorteil)
            gridview: true,
            // Automatisches HTML-Encoding
            autoencode: true,
            // 
            prmNames: {id:'libraries.id'}, 
            editurl:"./jqGridResults/xmlCustomersOverview.jsp",
            onSelectRow: function(ids){
                var $self = $("#list_Contacts");    
                if(bLinkedTables == true){
                    if(ids != null){
                        if(ids.length == 0){
                            $self.jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?libraries_id=0&bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }else if(ids.length == 10){
                            $self.jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?libraries_id="+ids+"&bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                            $self.jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables});
                    }
                }
            },
            resizeStop: function (newWidth, iCol) {
                var $self = $(this);
                $self.jqGrid("setColWidth", iCol, newWidth);
                shrinkToFit = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "shrinkToFit");
                $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth", this.grid.newWidth, shrinkToFit);
            },
            loadComplete: function(){

                //Wenn Tabellenverknüpfung aktiv ist
                var userdata = jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');

                if(userdata.linkedTables === 'true'){
                    jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?libraries_id=0&bLinkedTables="+userdata.linkedTables}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    //jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('setCaption',"Selektieren Sie einen Datensatz aus der BVB-Kundenübersicht, um lokale Ansprechpartner zu finden.");
                }

                var $self = $(this);
                var aCustomersOverviewIds = $self.jqGrid("getDataIDs");
                var hLibTypesFull = new Object();
                hLibTypesFull['B'] = "Behördenbibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['F'] = "Fachhochschulbibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['H'] = "Hochschulbibliohek";
                hLibTypesFull['K'] = "Kirchliche Bibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['Ö'] = "Öffentliche Bibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['R'] = "Regional Staatliche Bibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['S'] = "Spezialbibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['U'] = "Universitätsbibliothek";
                hLibTypesFull['Z'] = "Zweigbibliothek";

                for(var i = 0; i < aCustomersOverviewIds.length; i++){
                    var sLibTypeShort = $self.jqGrid('getCell',aCustomersOverviewIds[i],"libraries.type_of_institution");
                    $self.jqGrid('setCell',aCustomersOverviewIds[i],"libraries.type_of_institution", hLibTypesFull[sLibTypeShort]);
                }

                // JSON-Objecte zur Anzeigensteuerung der Buttons in der Navigationsleiste      
                var oOptionsPrivate = {edit:true, add:true, del:true, search:true, view:true, refresh:true}; 
                var oOptionsPublic  = {edit:false, add:false, del:false, search:true, view:true, refresh:true};

                // Button-Konfiguration :: Editieren 
                var oConfEdit =  {
                    closeAfterEdit:false,
                    width: 'auto',
                    afterSubmit: function (response){
                        return generateSuccesssMessage(response,"edit", $.jgrid.jqID(this.id));
                    },
                    errorTextFormat:function(data){
                        return generateErrorMessage(data,"edit");   
                    }
                };

                // Button-Konfiguration :: Hinzufuegen 
                var oConfAdd = {
                    closeAfterAdd:false,
                    reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                    closeOnEscape:true,
                    width: 'auto',
                    beforeInitData: function () {
                        var rowidCustomersOverview = $self.jqGrid('getGridParam','selrow');
                        if(rowidCustomersOverview !== null){
                            selRowData = $self.jqGrid('getRowData', rowidCustomersOverview);
                        }else{
                            selRowData = null;
                        }
                    },
                    afterSubmit: function (response){
                        return generateSuccesssMessage(response,"add", $.jgrid.jqID(this.id));
                    },
                    errorTextFormat:function(data){
                        return generateErrorMessage(data,"add");    
                    }
                };

                // Button-Konfiguration :: Loeschen 
                var oConfDelete = {
                    reloadAfterSubmit:false,
                    closeAfterEdit:false,
                    width: "auto",
                    errorTextFormat: function(data){
                        return generateErrorMessage(data,"delete"); 
                    }
                };

                // Button-Konfiguration :: Suchen 

                var template1 = 
                    { "groupOp": "AND",
                        "rules": [
                                    { "field": "libraries.icode_isil_of_leader_lib", "op": "bw", "data": ""},
                                    { "field": "libraries.location_city", "op": "bw", "data": ""}
                                ]
                    };

                var template2 = 
                    { "groupOp": "AND",
                        "rules": [
                                    { "field": "libraries.type_of_institution", "op": "bw", "data": "" },
                                    { "field": "libraries.location_city", "op": "bw", "data": ""}
                                ]
                    };

                var oConfSearch = {
                    multipleSearch:true,
                    afterShowSearch:function(){$self[0].clearToolbar()},
                    closeAfterSearch:true,
                    showQuery:false,
                    multipleGroup:false,
                    caption:"BVB-Kunden&uuml;bersicht :: Erweiterte Suche",
                    tmplNames: ["Leit-ISIL und Ort","Typ und Ort"],
                    // set the template contents
                    tmplFilters: [template1, template2]         
                };

                // Button-Konfiguration :: Anzeige 
                var oConfView = {
                    width: '700', 
                };

                // Steuerung der Butttons in der Navigationsleiste (privater vs. oeffentlicher Bereich) 
                <%
                    // Liegt die aktuelle SessionID bereits vor in validsessions?
                    if(res.first()){
                %>
                    $self.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_CustomersOverview', oOptionsPrivate, oConfEdit, oConfAdd, oConfDelete, oConfSearch, oConfView, {});
                    $self.jqGrid("showCol","libraries_id"); 
                    var newWidthContacts = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam","width");
                    if(newWidthContacts === 1265){
                        var extraWidth = newWidthContacts + 75;
                        $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth", extraWidth, false);
                    }else{
                        $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidthContacts, false);
                    }

                <%
                    }else{
                %>
                    $self.jqGrid('navGrid','#pager_CustomersOverview', oOptionsPublic, {}, {}, {}, oConfSearch, oConfView, {});
                    $self.jqGrid("hideCol","libraries_id");
                    var newWidthContacts = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam","width");

                    $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth", newWidthContacts, false);
                <%
                    }  
                %>      

                // Custom Button :: ColumnChooser
                if(bColumnChooser_CustomersOverview == false){

                    $self.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#pager_CustomersOverview", {
                        caption: "",
                        buttonicon: "ui-icon-calculator",
                        title: "Spalten auswählen",
                        onClickButton: function () {
                            $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser",{
                                modal:true,
                                done : function (perm) {
                                   if (perm){
                                    this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true);
                                    this.trigger('reloadGrid');
                                   }
                               }
                            });
                        }
                    }); 

                    bColumnChooser_CustomersOverview = true;
                }   

                // Button-Separator 
                //  $('#list_CustomersOverview').jqGrid('navSeparatorAdd',"#pager_CustomersOverview",{ sepclass: 'ui-separator', sepcontent: ''}); 



                // Custom Button :: ResetColumn-Button 
                $self.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager_CustomersOverview',{
                    caption: "",    
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-close",
                    id:"customButtonReset",
                    title: "Tabellen zurücksetzen",
                    position: "Reset",
                    onClickButton: function(){
                         window.location.reload();
                    }
                });


                // Zusatzfunktion :: Schalter zur Verknuepfung der Tabellen. Selektion einer Zeile in Kundenuebersicht loest Suche in Lokale Ansprechpartner aus 
                var bRadioButton = false;   
                var sTitleBeforeClickRadio = "Tabellenverknüpfung aktivieren";
                var sTitleAfterClickRadio = "Tabellenverknüpfung deaktivieren";
                var iconOff = "ui-icon-radio-on";

                // Custom Buttom :: Radio 
                $self.jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager_CustomersOverview",{
                    caption:"",
                    title:sTitleBeforeClickRadio,
                    buttonicon:iconOff, 
                    id:"customButtonRadio",
                    onClickButton:function(){
                        if(bRadioButton == false){
                            bLinkedTables = true;   
                            jQuery("#customButtonRadio").attr('title',sTitleAfterClickRadio);
                            jQuery(".ui-icon.ui-icon-radio-on").removeClass("ui-icon-radio-on").addClass("ui-icon-bullet"); 

                            //TEST  bLinkedTables Parameter
                            jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?libraries_id=0&bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables});

                            var sGridContacts = jQuery("#list_Contacts");
                            sGridContacts[0].clearToolbar();

                            //TEST
                            jQuery("#search_list_Contacts").hide();
                            jQuery("#refresh_list_Contacts").hide();
                            jQuery("tr[class='ui-search-toolbar']:last").hide();
                            //TEST  bLinkedTables Parameter
                            jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables});
                            bRadioButton = true;
                        }else{
                            bLinkedTables = false;  
                            jQuery("#customButtonRadio").attr('title',sTitleBeforeClickRadio);
                            jQuery(".ui-icon.ui-icon-bullet").removeClass("ui-icon-bullet").addClass("ui-icon-radio-on");

                            //TEST  
                            jQuery("#list_Contacts").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"./jqGridResults/xmlLibrariesContacts.jsp?bLinkedTables="+bLinkedTables});
                            jQuery("#search_list_Contacts").show();
                            jQuery("#refresh_list_Contacts").show();
                            jQuery("tr[class='ui-search-toolbar']:last").show();
                            jQuery("#list_Contacts").trigger('reloadGrid');

                            bRadioButton = false;
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Custom Button :: Hilfe 
                $self.jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager_CustomersOverview',{
                    caption: "Hilfe",   
                    buttonicon: "ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s",
                    id:"instructionManual",
                    title: "Download Bedienungsanleitung",
                    position: "last",
                    onClickButton: function(){
                         window.open("./documents/BVB_CDB_INSTRUCTION_MANUAL.pdf","_blank");
                    }
                });         

                $self.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager_CustomersOverview");
                $("#view_list_CustomersOverview").insertAfter("#search_list_CustomersOverview");

                var ids = $self.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                var sortName = $self.jqGrid('getGridParam','sortname');
                var sortOrder = $self.jqGrid('getGridParam','sortorder');

               var mymodelCustomers = $self.jqGrid('getGridParam','colModel'); 
               $.each(mymodelCustomers, function(i){
                if(this.name == sortName && this.hidden == false){
                        if (ids) {
                            for (var i=0;i<ids.length;i++) {
                                $self.jqGrid('setCell', ids[i], sortName, '', '',
                                            {style:(sortOrder==='asc'?'background:#fbec88;':
                                                                      'background:#fbec88;')});
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                });


                //Mindestgroesse Tabelle
                var gridWidth = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam","width");
                if(gridWidth <= 500){
                    $self.jqGrid("setGridWidth",550);   
                    $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
                }
            }
        });

        // Zusatzfunktion :: Steuerung ueber Tastatur aktivieren 
        jQuery("#list_CustomersOverview").jqGrid('bindKeys');

        // Zusatzfunktion :: Toolbarsuche  mit datenspezifischen Suchoperatoren einbinden 
        jQuery("#list_CustomersOverview").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult:true, searchOnEnter:false, searchOperators:true});

        // Zusatzfunktion: Toolbarsuche nach paste ausloesen
        jQuery("#gbox_list_CustomersOverview input[id^='gs_']").attr("onpaste","triggerToolbar('#list_CustomersOverview')");

        // Zusatzfunktion :: Hinzufuegen einer Division zur Informationsausgabe auf der ToolBar
        jQuery("<div><span id='list_InfoToolBar' style:'float:left;'></span></div>").appendTo("#t_list_CustomersOverview");

        jQuery("#pager_CustomersOverview .ui-pg-selbox").closest("td").before("<td dir='ltr'>max.</td>");
        jQuery("#pager_CustomersOverview .ui-pg-selbox").closest("td").after("<td dir='ltr'>Datens&auml;tze pro Seite anzeigen</td>");

    }); 
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you post the current JavaScript code which you use? Please write always which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork.

Comment: Try to change jqGrid URLs to the URLs `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.0/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css`, `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.min.js` and `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.12.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and verify whether the problem exist in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.12.0. jqGrid 4.7 have many bugs which I fixed in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you for your support. Unfortunately if I change URLs the hole grid got distorted. Playing around with roeordering columns I got the following error: TypeError: a(...)[0] is undefined
.filterToolbar/</<()
 jquery.jqGrid.min.js:226
m.event.dispatch()
 jquery-1.11.1.min.js:3
m.event.add/r.handle()

Comment: Can you give me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: If you get an error you should always use `jquery.jqgrid.src.‌​js` instead of `jquery.jqgrid.min.‌​js` and report the exact error message with the line number of `jquery.jqgrid.src.‌​js`. The only way in which one can go forward is providing the demo which reproduces the problem. At least you should provide the test XML data returned from `'./jqGridResults/xmlCustomersOverview.jsp`. You current code contains `<% ...%>` with `res.first()` parts. Many parts of the code not important to reproduce the reported problem. You should just prepare clean JavaScript demo in JSFiddle for example.